# Loop through data frame and append to a new empty one

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have csv file with data like this

```
     a   b     c     
     1   2  'some string1' 
     1   54 'some string2' 
     2   87 'some string3' 
     3   18 'some string4'
```

I need to loop through each data and copy the data one another data frame. So I need something like this

```
df <- read.csv("example.csv", sep='\t', header=TRUE)
new_df <- data.frame(a=NA, b=NA, c=NA)
for (row in df){
 #some calculation here then
 append(row to new_df)
}
save the new_df to a new csv.
```

How can I do this? I found lots of solutions but all seems confusing to me.

Comment: `df=rbind(df,the.new.row.to.append)`

Comment: I think the OP wants to append to a new empty data frame, not the original data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Loops and append is a very inefficient way to create new data frames. Most R programmers will recommend you transform the original data frame using a function from the `apply` family or a newer package such as `dplyr` or `purrr`.

It would help to know what "some calculation" is in your example code. But let's say, for example, that you wanted to multiple column `a` by 6. A "dplyr way" could be:

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(a = a * 6)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I really need to loop through the dataframe and create a new one without apply or a new package

Answer (score 0):

I will call the #some calculation here then `some_calculation`. Then you can construct your new dataframe from the rows of the old one with:

`new_df <- apply(df, 1, some_calculation)`

And then append it to the old one using `rbind` as pointed out earlier.